# Select by attribute in Selenium

Tags: selenium, select

Is there a way to select by attribute? We have select drop down with incomplete visible text. We have to rely only on  title. Is there a way to select by attribute?

My HTML looks something like

```
<select id="some ID" name="some Name" class="some class"
<option value="random number" title="testing pvt ltd">testing...</option>
<option value="random number" title="selenium HQ documentation">testing... 
</option>
<option value="random number" title="selenium HQ API Request">selenium HQ... 
</option>
```

Comment: Code trials please

Comment: No but you can get the value of attribute in webdriver then form it in xpath or css then perform any opertion

Comment: Only we can use value attribute to select but it is random here. You can write some custom method to select the value by attribute.

Comment: Can't you use a CSS selector? Something like 'option[title="...."]'

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, but nothing prevents you from implementing that method yourself, should you need it.

Something like this in C# should do the trick. Translation in your favourite language shouldn't be too hard.

```
public IWebElement GetWebElementByAttributeValue(string tagType, string attributeName, string attributeValue)
{
   //finds all tags of a type, for example h1,a,etc...
   //Here Driver is my instance of WebDriver

   var allTags = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//" + tagType));

   //iterate over all elements of that tag, and find the one whose attribute value you want

   foreach (var v in allTags)
        {             
           if ((v.GetAttribute.getText().equals(attributeName))
               return v;             
        }
        return null;
}
```

for you you would call it like that :

```
WebElement chosenOption = GetWebElementByAttributeValue("option","title","testing pvt ltd");
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Naturally - the locators will go after the specific attribute and value.
Here are samples based on your source; xpath:

```
//select/option[@title="testing pvt ltd"]
```

If you're not familiar with xpath, it reads - select the `option` element that is a direct descendant (e.g. a child) of a `select` one, **and** has an attribute `title` (note the `@` char, which denotes thst an attribute name follows) with that value.

Absolutely the same with CSS:

```
select>option[title="testing pvt ltd"]
```

In general in CSS you can skip the double quotes around the value, **if** there's no whitespace in it - not like in your case, they are needed here.

Answer (score 0):

`el("input[value*='Edit'][type='submit']")`

works without issue. I am using Fluentlenium and it makes thing a whole lot easier.

Answer (score -1):

Use selectByValue method under Select class.

Comment: Please, add example code to clarify your answer.

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 `Select selectExample = new Select(WebElement);
selectExample. selectByValue(value);`
//value will be value attribute from option tagName